# Pymongo mongodb query sort two values

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo 4.1.1 and i am trying to sort by two things at once.

A: The users word count

B: The last time they said an word.

Plan: My plan was to make an weekly server leaderboard for the most active user.

Code:

```
test=BADword.aggregate([
        {"$match":{"guild":UWUserver}},
        {"$sort":{"lastWORD":-1,"weeklyCount":-1}},
    ])
```

I am storing the last word like: `1649964397333`.
My idea was to first match the guild and then the lastWORD time and check if that is within this week. But can i even do that? I did not found anything how i could make a check in the $match where it checks for current period of time and only takes those who are within this week. ie. epochmilli since that is how i store the last word...

Comment: would be helpful if you can provide sample dataset (in json documents) and expected output.

Comment: You can possibly convert the epochmillis to a Date object within the aggregation using one of the Aggregation Date Operators. The converted date (or its components) can be matched with an input date.